# Email system is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I just created the magento site and everything is working properly except Email system :(
Magento is not sending emails when customer place order and not even when i send email from **orders**.

> I don't know what happened  with it  i tried everything on magento
>   forum i also installed cron jobs and config email in system
>   configuration but now luck :(  Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: which magento version  1.x or 2.x

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.0

Comment: may be this is useful for you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450413/magento-1-9-1-0-order-confirmation-emails-not-sending

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the possible trivial question, but had you enabled the email sending in magento?

If yes try to see what is write in the log files inside var/log.

Check also if you have installed something like postfix in your server.